# English to Quantifier every real number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

how to write this statement

> "every real number is not greater than six"

in symbols (quantifiers)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know what the quantifier "for every" looks like symbolically?

Comment: @SeanRoberson i know what are quantifiers but i don't have any idea how to write this :)

Comment: I suggest you look at your notes or examples and try. That will increase your chances of getting an answer. This isn't a place to just dump questions without an attempt at a solution. With that, I encourage you to give it a shot.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thnx for your suggest, but as if i know the answer I will not asked the question

Comment: Why is this Question interesting?  Is it important to be able to say this with symbols?  I would begin by trying to say it "in English" as a complete sentence with less ambiguity than it currently appears to have.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol for "for every, for each, for all, for any" is $\forall$. Now, we can write

$$ \forall x: x \not > 6 $$

But can we clean this up? Ah, yes we can. If a real number is not greater than 6, then what? It must be less than or equal to 6. So we may then write

$$ \forall x: x \leq 6$$

and move on.

Comment: "every real number is not greater than six" is a true statement and $ \forall x : x \le 6 $ is a false statement !

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to write it in stack exchange or just in general? If the former, there are several good posts in stack exchange that go over how to format here. A simple google search of something like "how to format questions in math stack exchange" or something like that should bring them up. If it is the latter, you'd write $\forall x \in \Bbb R, x \ngtr 6$

Comment: Here's the link: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference